# Python remove item from list where only part of item is known

Tags: python

I have a list of things like this:

```
My_list = [['A1'],['B2'],['C3']]
```

I am asking the user to enter a LETTER (only) indicating which element to delete. So, for example, if the user entered 'B', the 2nd entry should be deleted and the list should look like this:

```
My_list = [['A1'],['C3']]
```

I have tried several solutions, but below is my best attempt at this...and i believe i'm  not too far away from the final answer.

```
My_list = [['A1','B2','C3']]

print('What LETTER pairing would you like to delete?')
get_letter = input()
delete_letter = get_letter.upper()

for each_element in My_list:
    for each_pair in each_element:
        if each_pair[0] == delete_letter:
            location = My_list.index(each_pair)
            clues_list.pop(location)
            print('done')
```

when i run and enter 'B' the Compile error says...

```
ValueError: 'B2' is not in list
```

...but B2 is in list!

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Note that `My_list` is a list of lists, not a list of strings.

Comment: also, why are you pairing up A with 1, B with 2, etc? what's the point of that?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct: `'B2'` is **not** in `My_list`, although `['B2']` is!

You need to remove `each_element`, not `each_pair`, and should not do so while iterating over the list. For example, try:

```
location = None
for index, each_element in enumerate(My_list):
    for each_pair in each_element:
        if each_pair[0] == delete_letter:
            location = index
            break
if location is not None:
    My_list.pop(location)
```

However, it seems likely that a different data structure would be more useful to you, e.g. a dictionary:

```
data = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

where the code becomes as simple as:

```
if delete_letter in data: 
    del data[delete_letter]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have it done in a much more concise way (using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```
My_list = [['A1','B2','C3']]

get_letter = raw_input('What LETTER pairing would you like to delete? ')
delete_letter = get_letter.upper()
print delete_letter
new_list = [var for var in My_list[0] if delete_letter not in var]
print new_list
```

A few caveats: `not in` will try to find `delete_letter` *anywhere* in the variable, so if you want it to have more exact matches you can look into `.startswith`. Then, my piece of code blindly follows your list of lists.

Comment: what difference does raw_input have compared to input()?

Comment: Answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) :) Also contains answers about python 2.

Comment: @user3396486: if you're using Python 3, (which your `print` syntax suggests), the chief difference is that `raw_input` will give you a NameError and the `print` here is a syntax error...

Comment: (Calling `str()` on the results of `raw_input` is pointless... it always returns a `str` anyway.)

Comment: Yeah, indeed, I was playing around with `input()`, forgot to remove.